# Exporting a MySQL database with FTP access only

Tags: php, mysql, database, export

Hay guys, i need to export a MySQL database, but i only have access to the FTP server.

How could i export the DB? Are there any scripts i could upload and run to export the database? I have the username/password for the database, but i cannot connect to the database through my local MySQL client.

Comment: Does the mysqld have write-access to an area where you have read-access? If so, do a SELECT INTO OUTFILE and copy the file using FTP.

Comment: interesting. I'm assuming you cannot access the database via a web interface such as phpMyAdmin?

Comment: If you can access only the FTP server, and not the MySQL server then, no, you cannot do this. The FTP server and MySQL server are not linked. It sounds like you _do_ in fact have access to the server through web scripts (otherwise why tag this question "php"?) so just do your backup through a PHP script...

Comment: How would you run a script which you have uploaded via FTP? Just out of curiosity

Comment: @Brian - I installed phpmyadmin on the server, but i cannot connect to the MySQL server. I have a script called "conn.php" which is globally included which connects to the server just fine.

Comment: @jan - By pointed my web browser to the url ;)

Comment: @dotty if you can connect to the database and run a PHP script then @Konerak's solution should work for you.

Comment: @brian - What happens if i do not know what all the tables are called.

Comment: that's what INFORMATION_SCHEMA is for...

Comment: @Brian - While phpmyadmin didn't work, sqlbuddy worked a charm. Care to make it a 'reply', so i can mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to install [MySQLdumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/). It is a web-based (PHP or Perl) scripted tool to dump MySQL. I have had varying success on crappy servers where even PHPMyAdmin failed with this.

Comment: This worked well for me, in this exact situation. Be careful of a couple of minor points: (1) Unzipping the generated *.sql.gz files gave me  empty .sql files - I had to install and use MySQLDumper on the target machine to get the tables restored, (2) it restored the tables into the wrong database!